# Flexible, in-line variable assignment

Tags: python

I'd like to flexibly assign a value to a variable in Python, no matter where in my code that variable is.

For instance, given a variable `x` in an if statement:

```
if(x == 5):
    print "that's odd."
else:
    print "Woot."
```

I'd like to be able to assign `x` right in the if statement like this:

```
if((x=3) == 5):
    print "that's odd."
else:
    print "Woot."
```

Is that possible? Here's another example. Let's say I have a line that's:

```
y = x + 10
```

I'd like to assign x right there:

```
y = (x=3) + 10
```

So I'm looking for a way to find a variable anywhere in my code and give it a value assignment. Is there a pythonic syntax for that?

Comment: That's not possible in Python. Assignment to a variable can happen only as a separate statement.

Comment: I hope that it is not possible in python. Declaring a variable and then using it in the same line? why do you want to declare it as a variable in the first place?

Comment: Please don't pollute our otherwise beautiful language with C-isms :-)

Answer (score 19):

In Python 3.8+, you can use [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (operator `:=`):

```
if (x := 3) == 5:
    print("that's odd")

y = (x := 3) + 10
```

Answer (score 6):

"In Python, assignment is a statement, not an expression, and can therefore not be used inside an arbitrary expression. This means that common C idioms like:

```
while (line = readline(file)) {
    ...do something with line...
}
```

or

```
if (match = search(target)) {
    ...do something with match...
}
```

cannot be used as is in Python. "

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm

Answer (score 1):

globals().**setitem**('a',1) or a

this is a bit hacky,
but 2 things are possible,
declare/assign a variable through the locals() or globals() function.
use `or` to chain an inplace function (that returns None).

i doubt using either of those is consider a good practice, but they are available

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support Inline assignment. Why? Because everything is an object, and objects should be callable. Example:

This is not possible is python
`if ((x=10) > 20):`

Here we are assigning `x` as an instance of the `Int` class and executing it in the `if` expression.

Although such a statement is possible in C/C++ because it's build with a different mindset.

Comment: please elaborate else no gain by the cryptic answer.