# Can I resolve an if statement with the return value of a function then refer to that value without calling it again?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the return value of a function to control an `if` statement:

```
if my_func(arg):  
  do something
  return my_func(arg)
```

Is there a way to refer to the return value in the `if` block?
EDIT: Found this relevant question:
[python flexible, inline variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751423/python-flexible-inline-variable-assignment)
Looks like in-line variable assignment is not possible in Python.

Comment: Save it in a variable?

Comment: Hmm.. call it once and store its return value in a variable?

Comment: Why you want this way?

Comment: Yes, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in line of the 'if' statement. I have a series of functions that return 'none' when they are not applicable. So I am calling these functions on my data in order. If any of the functions return a value, I want to do something, THEN return that value.

Comment: Why does that keep you from saving the value temporarily for each function? It sounds like you're evaluating functions in some order then *returning the first applicable* value; is that right? if so, you may want to reconsider how you're going about this. Are these ordered calls written out explicitly and serially; can you give an example of the first two function calls (the way you'd like to do it)?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils mydata --> is_rank1(mydata) --> is_rank2(mydata) --> ...
If the function returns None, it continues down the pipeline. If it returns a value, then I want to do some things and then return that value.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
x=my_func(arg)
if x:  
   do something
   return x
```