# Combine in-place operator and assignment in one line

Tags: python

Is there any way to combine in-place and assignment operators in a single line?

Here's an example:

```py
result = ['a', 'b'].append('c')
```

The `result` is `None`. An obvious solution is to write it two lines like this:

```py
result = ['a', 'b']
result.append('c')
```

Can we do that in a single line in Python?

Comment: Do the obvious thing. Note assignment isn't an operator: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements.

Comment: `(result := ['a', 'b']).append('c')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24751423/3001761

Comment: In this specific example, you could of course also do `result = ['a', 'b']  + ['c']` (and some other ways). But I can imagine other cases where this might be desired, e.g. for creating widgets in Tkinter and placing them with `pack` or `grid` in the same line...

Comment: @tobias_k The real use case is with `insert`, as I need the extra element in arbitrary place in the list.

Comment: Besides using `:=`, the other obvious answer would be: write a function for it, e.g. `listWith(lst, idx, item)` (assuming you need this several times in your code)

Comment: @DallogFheir That looks like the right answer - care to post it? And yeah, I know it's better to this in two lines, it's far more readable this way. I was simply curious if there's a language feature that would allow me to do this in two lines.

Comment: This would be `result = ['a', 'b'].__iadd__(['c'])` but I fail to see the point. Can you edit the question with a motivating use-case please?

Comment: @wim See a few comments back; I guess what OP wants is something like `b = a.insert(k, x)` but with `b` ending up as `a` with `x`, not `None`.

Comment: I saw that comment, but it still doesn't explain why this needs to return the list. I'm still waiting to see a convincing use-case _edited into the question_. Asking how to do a thing in a single line for only the sake of doing it in a single line aren't really on-topic for stack overflow IMO.

Comment: Designing fluent APIs in Python is simple enough, you just write methods which `return self`. The standard types and the stdlib don't really encourage this style though, [it is considered unpythonic](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: do this at your own risk.

```py
(result := ['a', 'b']).append('c')
```

Comment: What do you mean, "at your own risk"? I guess it's debatable whether this is more readable, but what is risky about this? Not like messing with `locals` or `eval` stuff.

Comment: As someone said in a now deleted comment: this is morally wrong.

Comment: @DallogFheir "Starry sky above me and the moral law within me" :)